# Getting Error Unique constraint violation found - When remove suffix .html in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, suffix

I Am getting error when I am removing .html from Category URL Suffix. 
Error is `Unique constraint violation found`.

Anyone have genuine solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: it means you have used same url rewrites for two entities, you can look into url_rewrite table for it.

Comment: @Shiwani have you resolved an issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique constraint violation found - When remove suffix .html - Magento 2.2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205337/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-remove-suffix-html-magento-2-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by duplicate entries for the same product in **url_rewrite** database table.

You can check duplicate entries using below query.

```
SELECT * FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'product'
```

To resolve your issue [Follow this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205337/unique-constraint-violation-found-when-remove-suffix-html-magento-2-2-0)

I hope it helps.

Comment: No, I didn't resolve this

Comment: Have you tried the above answer? where did you stick?

Comment: I did all the steps. But still getting error at time of removing .html from Category URL Suffix

Comment: You may get this error`(Unique constraint violation found)` only on when there is some duplicate record or other databases issue. so you have to look into the database to resolve your issue.

Comment: I deleted the records from url_rewrite and save the all categories. But still not working